Hibernate does not rollback super class entity tables
I have an inheritance of type JOINED between User and RegisteredUser.
I have defined a unique constraint on the derived class entity (RegisteredUser).
When I create an object of the derived class and persist it twice, the second persist operation is throwing unique constraint violation as expected and the records are not inserted in the registered_users, but the parent table users gets 2 rows.
How can I rollback both users and registered_users tables when registered_users throws unique constraint violation?
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class User {
   @Id
   @SequenceGenerator(name = "USER_ID_GENERATOR", sequenceName="user_sequence", allocationSize = 1)
   @GeneratedValue(generator = "USER_ID_GENERATOR")
   @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
   private Long id;

   [...]
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "registered_users")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="user_id")
public class RegisteredUser extends User {}

@Override
@Transactional
public RegisteredUser registerNewUser(AccountInformationDTO accountInfo) {
    RegisteredUser newUser = new RegisteredUser();
    newUser.setUsername(accountInfo.getEmailAddress());
    newUser.setEmailAddress(accountInfo.getEmailAddress());
    newUser.setFirstName(accountInfo.getFirstName());
    newUser.setLastName(accountInfo.getLastName());

    return registeredUserDAO.save(newUser);
}

The save method is used by all DAOs:
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "entityManagerFactory")
private EntityManager entityManager;

@Override
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.MANDATORY)
public T save(T entity) {
    getEntityManager().persist(entity);
    return entity;
}

And the xml configuration:
<persistence-unit name="corePU" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    [..all models defined..]
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
</persistence-unit>

<bean id="persistenceUnitManager" depends-on="dataSource" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager">
[...]
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="corePU"/>
    <property name="persistenceUnitManager" ref="persistenceUnitManager"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="jpaDialect" ref="jpaDialect"/>
</bean>

We are using spring 5.3.27 and hibernate 5.5.5.Final
And here is the stack trace
 ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "registered_users_unique_username"
web-1  |   Detail: Key (username)=(lol3@aaa.ro) already exists.
web-1  | ERROR [2024-12-13 15:04:37,020]: w.c.b.LoginHandlerBehavior - Something went wrong when trying to login.
web-1  | org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException: JTA transaction unexpectedly rolled back (maybe due to a timeout); nested exception is javax.transaction.RollbackException: The transaction was set to rollback only
web-1  |        at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1038)
web-1  |        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)
web-1  |        at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)
web-1  |        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)
web-1  |        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)
web-1  |        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
web-1  |        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
web-1  |        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringSpringInterceptor.invoke(MonitoringSpringInterceptor.java:76)
web-1  |        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
web-1  |        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:220)
web-1  |        at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy338.login(Unknown Source)
web-1  |        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
web-1  |        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
web-1  |        at org.apache.wicket.proxy.jdk.JdkProxyFactory$JdkHandler.invoke(JdkProxyFactory.java:172)
web-1  |        at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy400.login(Unknown Source)
web-1  |        at project.web.components.behavior.LoginHandlerBehavior.loginUser(LoginHandlerBehavior.java:175)
web-1  |        at project.web.components.behavior.LoginHandlerBehavior.respond(LoginHandlerBehavior.java:102)
web-1  |        at org.apache.wicket.ajax.AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.onRequest(AbstractDefaultAjaxBehavior.java:630)
web-1  |        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.internalInvoke(ListenerRequestHandler.java:300)
web-1  |        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.invoke(ListenerRequestHandler.java:274)
web-1  |        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.invokeListener(ListenerRequestHandler.java:222)
web-1  |        at org.apache.wicket.core.request.handler.ListenerRequestHandler.respond(ListenerRequestHandler.java:202)
web-1  |        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle$HandlerExecutor.respond(RequestCycle.java:910)
web-1  |        at org.apache.wicket.request.RequestHandlerExecutor.execute(RequestHandlerExecutor.java:63)
web-1  |        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.execute(RequestCycle.java:294)
web-1  |        at org.apache.wicket.request.cycle.RequestCycle.processRequest(RequestCycle.java:255)
web-1  |        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequestCycle(WicketFilter.java:277)
web-1  |        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.processRequest(WicketFilter.java:208)
web-1  |        at org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WicketFilter.doFilter(WicketFilter.java:307)
web-1  |        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
web-1  |        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
web-1  |        at org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(DeviceResolverRequestFilter.java:60)
web-1  |        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)
web-1  |        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
web-1  |        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
web-1  |        at project.web.filter.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:29)
web-1  |        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
web-1  |        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
web-1  |        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:239)
web-1  |        at net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter.doFilter(MonitoringFilter.java:215)
web-1  |        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
web-1  |        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
web-1  |        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.handleNonCORS(CorsFilter.java:331)
web-1  |        at org.apache.catalina.filters.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:158)
web-1  |        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:168)
web-1  |        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:144)
web-1  |        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:168)
web-1  |        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
web-1  |        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:481)
web-1  |        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:130)
web-1  |        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
web-1  |        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:660)
web-1  |        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
web-1  |        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:346)
web-1  |        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:388)
web-1  |        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
web-1  |        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:928)
web-1  |        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(AprEndpoint.java:2165)
web-1  |        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
web-1  |        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1190)
web-1  |        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
web-1  |        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:63)
web-1  |        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
web-1  | Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: The transaction was set to rollback only
web-1  |        at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionImp.rethrowAsJtaRollbackException(TransactionImp.java:49)
web-1  |        at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionImp.commit(TransactionImp.java:192)
web-1  |        at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionManagerImp.commit(TransactionManagerImp.java:428)
web-1  |        at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.J2eeUserTransaction.commit(J2eeUserTransaction.java:77)
web-1  |        at org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager.doCommit(JtaTransactionManager.java:1035)
web-1  |        ... 62 common frames omitted
web-1  | Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:154)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:181)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:188)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1395)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:482)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3274)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2409)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:448)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletion(JtaTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:355)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:47)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jta.internal.synchronization.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:37)
web-1  |        at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.Sync2Sync.beforeCompletion(Sync2Sync.java:34)
web-1  |        at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.TransactionStateHandler.notifyBeforeCompletion(TransactionStateHandler.java:235)
web-1  |        at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.TransactionStateHandler.commit(TransactionStateHandler.java:210)
web-1  |        at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp.doCommit(CompositeTransactionImp.java:234)
web-1  |        at com.atomikos.icatch.imp.CompositeTransactionImp.commit(CompositeTransactionImp.java:274)
web-1  |        at com.atomikos.icatch.jta.TransactionImp.commit(TransactionImp.java:178)
web-1  |        ... 65 common frames omitted
web-1  | Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:109)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:200)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3379)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3906)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:107)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)
web-1  |        at java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:986)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1391)
web-1  |        ... 78 common frames omitted
web-1  | Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "registered_users_unique_username"
web-1  |   Detail: Key (username)=(lol3@aaa.ro) already exists.
web-1  |        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2725)
web-1  |        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2412)
web-1  |        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:371)
web-1  |        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:502)
web-1  |        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:419)
web-1  |        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:194)
web-1  |        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PgPreparedStatement.java:155)
web-1  |        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
web-1  |        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
web-1  |        at org.postgresql.ds.PGPooledConnection$StatementHandler.invoke(PGPooledConnection.java:447)
web-1  |        at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy78.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
web-1  |        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
web-1  |        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
web-1  |        at bitronix.tm.resource.jdbc.BaseProxyHandlerClass.invoke(BaseProxyHandlerClass.java:64)
web-1  |        at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy364.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
web-1  |        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
web-1  |        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
web-1  |        at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper.doExecute(JdbcWrapper.java:428)
web-1  |        at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$StatementInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:145)
web-1  |        at net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:306)
web-1  |        at jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy365.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
web-1  |        at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.executeUpdate(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:197)
web-1  |        ... 89 common frames omitted```


Your User class definition doesn't seem to work without @Id. Can you show a stack trace of the error?

Which version of spring and hibernate are you using? Also, could you attach the code in your RegisteredUserDAO class?

@AndreySmelik  User has @Id and many other fields. I added the @Id and the stack trace.

@SalvinoD'sa I attached the code. We are using <spring.version>5.3.27</spring.version> and <hibernate.version>5.5.5.Final</hibernate.version>
